# Script not running as Handler or in Driver

Tags: python, scripting, blender-internal-render-engine, drivers

Edit: [DOWNLOAD DEMO BLEND FILE](http://www.filedropper.com/driverglslissue)

I am running into a weird issue that I have solved in the past but can't seem to figure out now.

I have a material node keyframed in Blender Internal, and unfortunately blender does not show the transition in the GLSL textured viewport. So I have written a small script that will reinforce the value of a MixRGB factor to itself.

When I click on "Run Script" everything works fine and my material is updated. However assigning the function to a driver or even handler does need yield expected result, which is updating that MixRGB factor on every frame change.

```
import bpy

def refreshNow(val):
    mat = bpy.data.materials['Skin_Gloss']
    nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
    nodes["Mix"].inputs[0].default_value = nodes["Mix"].inputs[0].default_value
    bpy.context.scene.update()
    return val

refreshNow(0)

bpy.app.driver_namespace['refresh'] = refreshNow

def my_handler():
    refreshNow(0)

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_handler)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Below is my driver setup. As you can see the debug info shows my current frame, which is 115. Meaning that refreshNow is actually called and has returned.

[image: Driver Setup]

Here is my material setup, pay attention to the MixRGB being keyframed from 0 to 1, from frame 0 to 50:

[image]

Like I said, the script works fine when I click on "Run Script", and the driver shows that the function has returned. What could possibly be the issue?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: [DOWNLOAD DEMO BLEND FILE](http://www.filedropper.com/driverglslissue)

Comment: you need to add `bpy.context.scene.update()` at the end of the refreshNow() and the viewport will be updated

Comment: @Chebhou please look at the code above. I still fail to append my_handler. On Run Script material and viewport updates, but on play nothing changes

Comment: `my_handler()` should be   `my_handler(scene)`. ( looking at the error it should take one argument )

Comment: @Chebhou Wow! Lovely. That fixed everything. Handlers for the win.Thank you so so so much

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code that resulted in proper solution to my problem. Thanks to @Chebhou who provided help and resolved the issues in my code. Refer to the comments in the first post for clarification.

```
import bpy

def refreshNow(val):
    mat = bpy.data.materials['Material']
    nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
    nodes["Mix"].inputs[0].default_value = nodes["Mix"].inputs[0].default_value
    bpy.context.scene.update()
    return val

refreshNow(0)

bpy.app.driver_namespace['refresh'] = refreshNow
#scene parameter was missing in original code
def my_handler(scene):
    refreshNow(0)

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_handler)
# this was also missing from the original code, I still don't know what it does, but it works!    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

**===Alternative Solution Using Modal Operators===**

I managed to fix the issue by using a Modal Timer rather than utilizing handlers or drivers. This is not exactly a solution to why the driver or handler doesn't work but it is definitely a workaround to get what I wanted done.

Below is the code for anyone who might need it in future. This is simply the Modal Timer template, I just replaced the default functionality of changing theme color to reinforcing the MixRGB node's factor input to itself. I have also removed the functionality of cancelling the event.

```
import bpy


class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs its self from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    _timer = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
#        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
#            self.cancel(context)
#            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            mat = bpy.data.materials['Material']
            nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
            mix = nodes["Mix"].inputs[0]
            mix.default_value = mix.default_value
            print('Current Frame:')

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.1, context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```