# Run ModalOperatorTimer automatically on animation playback

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I have the following script. It updates a MixRGB node's factor input to itself to solve some issues with GLSL viewport in textured mode. Anyways, I was wondering if there is a way to attach this script, so that it runs automatically when I click on the "Play" button or press Alt-A and stop automatically as well when the playback is suspended?
What would be the easiest way to go about doing this? Is creating an addon a feasible solution?

```
import bpy


class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs its self from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    _timer = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
#        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
#            self.cancel(context)
#            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            mat = bpy.data.materials['Material']
            nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
            mix = nodes["Mix"].inputs[0]
            mix.default_value = mix.default_value
            print('Current Frame:')

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.1, context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```

I'm aware of Handlers in Blender. However I tried the below script with no luck:

```
import bpy

def refreshNow(val):
    mat = bpy.data.materials['Material']
    nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
    nodes["Mix"].inputs[0].default_value = nodes["Mix"].inputs[0].default_value
    return val

refreshNow(0)

bpy.app.driver_namespace['refresh'] = refreshNow

def my_handler():
    refreshNow(0)

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_handler)
```

Comment: instead of the timer attach the main function to the handler `bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre` and it will run before the frame change.  see [handlers](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bpy.app.handlers.html)

Comment: @Chebhou I have tried the handlers, and for some strange reason it does not work in this case (node manipulation for blender internal). Have a look at my previous question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46533/script-not-running-as-handler-or-in-driver

Comment: I have commented on the other question try it out please

Comment: if not working you can :   attach the modal Op to the handler ( just to trigger it at the start ) and inside the handler detach the Op from the handler ( so it won't be called while running )   , have a counter inside the Op and check if frame don't change for long time stop the Op

Comment: @Chebhou this is my first blender script and python code :D can you please guide me as to how to attach a class in this case modalop to handlers? To my knowledge handlers only accepts functions right? And also how to detach? I am good with the counter and can look in the api to find info about frame changes. Thank you again

Comment: just call it inside a function ( appended to handler )   and to detach remove this function from the handler

Comment: @Chebhou would it be something like this:


    `def my_handler(scene):
    bpy.ops.development.ModalTimerOperator('EXEC_DEFAULT')
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(my_handler)
    
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_handler)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)`

And then using a counter and if statements inside my execute manage if frames are still changing?

Comment: now you have all the ingredients,  I'll get back to you later

Comment: Your comments in the other thread provided the definite solution to my problem. Thank you again so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to the above problem is to use Handler rather than a Modal Operator.
Thanks to @Chebhou for his help in this thread and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46533/script-not-running-as-handler-or-in-driver?noredirect=1#comment78966_46533).

Below is a working solution to execute on playback using handlers:

```
import bpy

def refreshNow(val):
    mat = bpy.data.materials['Material']
    nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
    nodes["Mix"].inputs[0].default_value = nodes["Mix"].inputs[0].default_value
    bpy.context.scene.update()
    return val

refreshNow(0)

bpy.app.driver_namespace['refresh'] = refreshNow
def my_handler(scene):
    refreshNow(0)

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_handler)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```